# Custom URL for HTTP Proxy service in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to setup custom URL for http proxy in WSO2ESB 4.8.1. Here is the doc for that: http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/01/custom-urls-wso2-esb-proxy-services/.

Following the doc, I added "CustomURIBasedDispatcher" handler into axis2.xml and a parameter "ServiceURI" into proxy.

But it does not work still. Any idea what else could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

The document you are referring is for WSO2 ESB 3.0.0/3.0.1
Try with the below in your inSequence

```
  <inSequence>
     <property name="param1" expression="$url:path"/>
     <property name="param2" value="someValue"/>
     <send>
        <endpoint name="xyz">
           <http uri-template="http://localhost:8080/testservice/{param1}?xyz={param2}"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
```

Here "param1" is a URL Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You just using this:

```
<parameter name="ServiceURI">CustomNameProxy</parameter>
```

When you using proxy, the default name as URI is for your service, so if you want you service as custome URI (or different from Name), just use this code:

```
    <parameter name="ServiceURI">CustomNameProxy</parameter>
```